# Showing alert after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm beginner just learn how to code, I try to make some notification after submitting form then reload page, will show alert-success bootstrap, this is the code

```
// Bootstrap alert
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message){
  $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>').show(500).delay(3000).hide(500);
}

(function checkIfMsgSent() {
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    var isMsgSent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messageSent")); // JSON.parse because we want a boolean

    if (isMsgSent) {
      alert('Message has been sent.');
      // bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.');
    }

    localStorage.removeItem('messageSent');
  } else {
    // localStorage not defined
    alert('Your browser in incompatible for some features in this website');
  }
});

$('#sentcontact').on('click', function(){
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem('messageSent', 'true');
  } else {
    // localStorage not defined
    alert('Your browser in incompatible for some features in this website');
  }

  window.location.reload();
});
```

**Update Javascript Use by Solution 2**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="alert_placeholder"></div>
</div>

<section class="contact_us">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="vanilla-form-contact.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="name" class="label-control">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name..." required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="email" class="label-control">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..." required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="subject" class="label-control">Subject:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Your subject..." required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label for="message" class="label-control">Message:</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Messages..." class="form-control" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon/contact.png" alt="Contact Icon">
            <div>
              <p class="title_contact">Contact:</p>
              <p class="contact_phone"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> +000</p>
              <p class="contact_email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> email@email.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon/support.png" alt="Contact Icon">
            <div>
              <p class="title_contact">Support:</p>
              <p class="contact_phone"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> email@email.com</p>
              <p class="contact_email"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-custom" data-dismiss="alert" id="sentcontact">Send It</button>
     </form>
```

**This is my html**

[An error always show up when page reloaded in contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXagV.png)

**It always show up in my page each time I reload page, not after clicking submit button**

But, when I run that code, it just showing the bootstrap_alert first then reload the page. How could I make it reload page first then showing up bootstrap_alert?

Comment: I can see 2 possibilities. You need to store a state either in localstorage/cookie, or pass a parameter via URL (query string) and then on page load you check it.

Comment: Could you show me how to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it. An easy way to achieve this would be passing through a parameter in the URL and checking it on page load.

```
// Check the URL parameter on page load
$(function(){
    if(getUrlParameter('success') == '1') {
       bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.');
    }
});

// Set up the click event
$('#sentcontact').on('click', function(){
  if (true){
    var nextUrl = window.location.href;
    nextUrl += (nextUrl.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'success=1'
    window.location = nextUrl;
  }
});

// Simple function to read parameters out of the URL
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: I'm still can't get my message show up after the page reloading

Comment: Any errors in the console? Perhaps `bootstrap_alert.warning is undefined`?

Comment: Nothing error actually in console, but it still not showing up

Comment: Add this to your javascript and post here what it outputs to the console after you click on the send button: `$(function(){ console.log(window.location.href); })`

Comment: Before I put that code it always show an error in console Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .navbar-nav li a[href*=#]:not([href=#]), .site-logo a[href*=#]:not([href=#]) it calls error from jquery.min.js:2, but the code you make not show an error log in console

Comment: First of all, find in your project where this line is being called from and change it to `$(".navbar-nav li a[href*='#']:not([href='#']), .site-logo a[href*='#']:not([href='#'])")`. Then add the piece of code I sent above and post here the ouput.

Comment: After that error fix then show this error functions.js:619 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slide is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/compos/js/functions.js:619:24), is it effect to the form submit alert?

Comment: Yes, beside that nothing error show up in my console

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Modify `href` of the `window` when you programmatically reload, check for the hash fragment (`onload`) and decide to show the alert.

```
(function checkIfMsgSent() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if ((/#message_sent/).test(url)) {
    alert('Message has been sent.');
    // bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.');
  }
})();

$('#sentcontact').on('click', function(){
  if (true){
    window.location = window.location.href + "#message_sent";
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

---

#### Solution 2

Using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), but this won't work if browser doesn't support `localStorage` (almost all modern browsers do have it).

```
(function checkIfMsgSent() {
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    var isMsgSent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messageSent")); // JSON.parse because we want a boolean

    if (isMsgSent) {
      alert('Message has been sent.');
      // bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.');
    }

    localStorage.removeItem('messageSent');
  } else {
    // localStorage not defined
    alert('Your browser in incompatible for some features in this website');
  }
})();

$('#sentcontact').on('click', function(){
  if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem('messageSent', 'true');
  } else {
    // localStorage not defined
    alert('Your browser in incompatible for some features in this website');
  }

  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Solution 1 is work, but my alert notification always show when page reload, how could I make it show after reload when clicking submit button in form?

Comment: **Update** I got this message when I reload the page in alert function (){ var url = window.location.href; if ((/#message_sent/)) { //alert('Message has been sent.'); bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.'); } }, why not just show the "Message has been sent"? It's included the code

Comment: Got it, the alert will be shown whenever you have `#message_sent` at the end of your site url. (that is the side-effect of Solution 1). I recommend you to go with Solution 2, which is a better, idiomatic and reliable way to handle your situation. Please accept the answer if it works. :)

Comment: In your second comment, I see a typo, it is not `((/#message_sent/)) `, it should be `(/#message_sent/).test(url)`. But try Solution 2.. it is the best I can think of ;)

Comment: Umm, I got this message when reload the page 
`×function checkIfMsgSent() { if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') { var isMsgSent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messageSent")); // JSON.parse because we want a boolean if (isMsgSent) { alert('Message has been sent.'); // bootstrap_alert.warning('Message has been sent.'); } localStorage.removeItem('messageSent'); } else { // localStorage not defined alert('Your browser in incompatible for some features in this website'); } }`, even I reload wihout clicking submit, It always show that notification. I'm really stuck in here...

Comment: please update this in your question to understand your implementation. It is really hard to read it from the comment.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what is happening at your end. But I got it working in my machine before I posted the answer. See it here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0rn4VRjwc1cUU9GUFlPTF93NW8. It is an `.html` file, you can download and open it in your browser to see Solution 2 working.